# Prove that $F$ is finite field

Tags: field-theory

We denote $\mathbb{F}_q$ as finite field of $q$ elements and the algebraic clausure as $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_q$. Let

$$K=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{F}_{q_n}\subset \overline{\mathbb{F}}_3,\; \mbox{where}\, q_n=3^{2^n}.$$

Prove that if $F\subsetneqq K$ a proper subfield of $K$, then $F$ is finite field.

Thank you by some hints.

Comment: Hint: look at the Galois group.

Comment: I saw the Galois group: $Gal(\mathbb{F}_{3^{2^n}}/\mathbb{F}_3)\simeq \mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z}$, this group has only subgroups of the form $\mathbb{Z}/2^m\mathbb{Z}$, with $0\leq m \leq n$. Now I have use the fact that $F$ is a proper subgroup, but I not know as use it.

Comment: The full group, of $K$ over $\Bbb F_3$, is the inverse limit of these. Do you know what that is, and what its subgroups (and in particular what its quotients) are?

Comment: Sorry, but I have not seen this topic.